# Смена цвета tkinter при движении фигуры

Tags: python, tkinter

**1)** Нужно сделать так, чтобы при движении круга вправо, он менял свой цвет на протяжении всего движения на цвета, которые записаны в списке. Но устанавливается только один цвет, смены не происходит. В чём проблема?

```
colorlist = ["red","black","white","green"]
random_color = random.choice(colorlist)

def moving():
    canvas.move(shell, 1,0)
    canvas.itemconfigure(shell, fill=f"{random_color}")
    canvas.after(10,moving)
moving()

window.mainloop()
```

**2)** Сделал второй вид программы, но здесь цвет меняется только один раз и больше шарик не движется и не меняет цвет. Как можно сделать так, чтобы это всё происходило, допустим, пока он не дойдёт до конца окна?

```
colorlist = ["red","black","white","green"]
random_color = random.choice(colorlist)

def moving():
    canvas.coords(shell, canvas.coords(shell)[0]+10,15,canvas.coords(shell)[2]+10,105)
    canvas.itemconfig(shell, fill=f"{random_color}")
canvas.after(1000,moving)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Идею одновременного и движения, и изменения при этом цветов шариков можно реализовать с помощью потоков — threading

```
import tkinter, threading

...

shell1 = canvas.create_oval((15, 15), (105, 105), fill='#FFDE59',outline="#494949", width=8)

def moving1():
    if canvas.coords(shell1)[0] < 690:
        canvas.move(shell1, 1,0)
        canvas.after(10,moving1)
    if canvas.coords(shell1)[0] == 690:
        canvas.move(shell1,0,1)
        canvas.after(20,moving1)

def change_color():
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        colorlist = ["#f00","#ff0","#3f0","#00f","#f0f","#fff","#000000","#0000FF"]
        random_color = random.choice(colorlist)
        canvas.itemconfig(shell1, fill=f"{random_color}")
m1 = threading.Thread(target=moving1)
c1 = threading.Thread(target=change_color)

m1.start()
c1.start()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас `random_color` - глобальная переменная, и при вызове функции `moving` она не изменяется. Надо изменять её в каждом вызове, например так:

```py
colorlist = ["red", "black", "white", "green"]
random_color = random.choice(colorlist)


def moving():
    canvas.move(shell, 1, 0)
    canvas.itemconfigure(shell, fill=random_color)
    random_color = random.choice(colorlist)
    canvas.after(10, moving)


moving()

window.mainloop()
```

А лучше сделать её вообще локальной, например так:

```py
colorlist = ["red", "black", "white", "green"]


def moving():
    canvas.move(shell, 1, 0)
    random_color = random.choice(colorlist)
    canvas.itemconfigure(shell, fill=random_color)
    canvas.after(10, moving)


moving()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: В принципе, правильно, но тут вообще не нужна глобальная переменная, достаточно локальной,  просто нужно вызывать `random_color = random.choice(colorlist)` внутри moving до `canvas.itemconfigure(shell, fill=random_color)`